# Does this copy class method leak memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, properties

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    PoolFacility *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone]init];
    copy.name = [self.name copy];
    copy.type = [self.type copy];
    copy.phoneNumber = [self.phoneNumber copy];
    //make sure I get proper copies of my dictionaries
    copy.address = [self.address mutableCopy];  
    copy.webAddress = [self.webAddress copy];
    copy.prices = [self.prices mutableCopy];
    copy.pools = [self.pools mutableCopy];
    return copy;
}
```

Can anyone see any memory leaks?

Here's the property types:

```
NSString *name;
NSString *type;
NSMutableDictionary *address;

NSString *phoneNumber;
NSString *webAddress;   

NSMutableArray *prices;
NSMutableArray *pools;
```

Here are the property declarations:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *webAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *prices;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pools;
```

Comment: Retagged since it's not specific to iPhone, and other tags classify it better.

Comment: Call me a losernoob but this is the first time I've encountered `mutableCopy`. Anyone care to give me a quick explanation of how it differs from `copy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The properties defined as **copy** and not **retain** will have an extra copy when set as below (your code)

```
copy.name = [self.name copy];
copy.type = [self.type copy];
copy.phoneNumber = [self.phoneNumber copy];
copy.webAddress = [self.webAddress copy];
```

it should be sufficient to only write them as

```
copy.name = self.name;
copy.type = self.type;
copy.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber;
copy.webAddress = self.webAddress;
```

Comment: But wont this defeat the point of a copy method? I'll be duplicating the class but the variables will point to the same objects? Or will this give me 2 completely independent objects?

Comment: The "@property (..., copy)" means that a copy is created when you use the dot-notation. The previous value will be sent a release.

Comment: Dan Morgan: The synthesized accessors will copy the objects for you because you declared the properties as `@property(copy)`. If you copy the objects yourself, the accessors will copy those copies. Since you aren't releasing those intermediate copies, they are all leaked.

Comment: All copied objects will leak. It does not depend on the property type (copy or retain).

Answer (score 1):

This almost certainly leaks like a sieve. You need to provide your @property and other method declarations for us to recommend the best way to fix it.